# Powershell IE Automation- Can't specify textbox by ID or TagName

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation

I am trying to use powershell to enter text into two text boxes. I can enter a value into the first box, but not the second. This is due to the fact that I don't know how to isolate the second textbox as it has the same code as the first text box including things such as ID, Class, TagName, etc.

Below is my code with the URL taken out (due to work). I had initially thought to isolate the second textbox by using -ne on the value of the first since by inputting a value it differentiated the code, however this doesn't seem to work. I am new to coding so my apologies if I'm expressing myself poorly, but any help you could provide would be appreciated.

[Here are two text boxes, I can enter a value into the first one using powershell but I am unable to isolate the second text box to enter a value into it. This is due to the two lines of code being identical- See second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4wuV.png)

[As you can see the two lines of code for input are identical and as such I cannot use GetElementById/TagName/Name to identify which text box I want powershell to enter the value into.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgkLF.png)

```
$Web = "URL"
$Internet = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$Internet.visible = $true
$Internet.Navigate($web)

While($Internet.Busy -eq $true){
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

$Internet.document.getElementById("filterValue").value="Number"
$link = $Internet.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'Next Prompt'}
$link.click()

While($Internet.Busy -eq $true){
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
**#Question about coding starts here**

$Input = $Internet.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("filterValue") 
$Input.value = "1/1/2020"

While($Internet.Busy -eq $true){
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

$Input2 = $Internet.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("filterValue") | ? {$_.value -ne "1/1/2020"}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 4 
$Input2.value = "1/2/2020"
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the image of HTML code and looks like there are some issues with the HTML code.

[image]

1. The ID of the HTML element should be unique. That means there cannot be more than one element that has the same ID on a single web page.
2. I also notice that the input element has / at the end of it for closing it. There are 2 more closing input tags after it. In HTML, there is no end tag for the Input element. So this is invalid HTML code.
3. Verify and confirm that you are referring to the correct code for those 2 textboxes. Try to use developer tools to view the HTML for those 2 textboxes.

I suggest you contact the developer of the website and inform them about this issue.